# Why can't I reset a Due Date in a customized Approval Workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a customized Sharepoint 2010 Approval Workflow that has triggered a Task. I want to be able to edit the Due Date manually, but when I try, it is a Read Only field. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You should create new task form fields . You can achieve this in SharePoint designer:

-Add a workflow for a List.

-Add a ‘Start Approval Process’ action in the workflow.

-Click on ‘these users’ to add the approvers.

-Click on Approval(1) to edit the task process.

-Add a new task form field named "New due date".( Add a task form field here will automatically create the field in the list after publish it).

-Click on Change the behavior of a single task .

-Define a workflow variable named "Var due date".

-Add a "Set workflow variable" in "When a task completes" section .

-Click on "workflow variable" and choose "var due date".

-Click on "value" and select "Current task:Approve(1)" as data source .

-In field from source dropdown list you can see all the task form fields.
-Choose "New due date" and click OK .

Now you have the new due date value in "var due date" variable. Then follow these steps :

-Add another ‘Start Approval Process’ action in the workflow. 

-Click on ‘these users’ to add the approvers.

-Click on Approval(2) to edit the task process.

-Click on Change the behavior of a single task .

-In "Before a task is assigned" step add "Set task field" (in Action / Task behavior action)

-Click on "Field" and select "Due Date".

-Click on "Value" and select "Workflow variables and parameters" in data source .

-Select your variable (varduedate). then publish it.

I hop it's useful for you .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new task form field in SPD and get new due date from approver and add a new action to update your due date  .
Good luck .

Comment: Can you please extend this answer. It needs more detail to be really useful